Building RISC-V compiler seems to fail, looking for extension
I am building a GCC compiler from source for RISC-V. I needed to compile GCC's dependencies locally as the PC does not have internet.
I've tailored a couple CPP flags to change clock settings; you can see all my set env variables below. I use the PREFIX var to easily provide paths to the built dependencies:
PREFIX=/nobackup/builddir
CPP_FLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC=1 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_REALTIME=1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PREFIX/mpc/lib:$PREFIX/mpfr/lib:$PREFIX/gmp/lib:$PREFIX/isl/lib
C_INCLUDE_PATH=$PREFIX/mpc/include:$PREFIX/mpfr/include:$PREFIX/gmp/include:$PREFIX/isl/include

And the configure/make command I'm using:
../gcc-13.2.0/configure --target=riscv64-unknown-elf --with-gmp=$PREFIX/gmp 
--with-mpfr=$PREFIX/mpfr --with-mpc=$PREFIX/mpc --with-isl=$PREFIX/isl --disable-shared --enable-static 
--disable-multilib --prefix=$PREFIX/riscv64-unknown-elf --enable-languages=all

Running configure finishes with no errors or warnings. However, running 'make' will be able to run awhile, until what seems like final steps. I get several of the following error, which what seems like is running an assembler and looking for a RISC-V architecture flag:
/nobackup/builddir/build/./gcc/as: 114: exec: -march=rv64imafdc_zicsr: not found
../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/m2/Make-lang.in:1586: recipe for target '/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2/gm2-libs-corou
tines/SYSTEM.def' failed
make[2]: *** [/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2/gm2-libs-coroutines/SYSTEM.def] Error 1

/nobackup/builddir/build/./gcc/as: 114: exec: -march=rv64imafdc_zicsr: not found
../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/m2/Make-lang.in:1568: recipe for target '/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2/gm2-libs/SYSTEM
.def' failed
make[2]: *** [/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2/gm2-libs/SYSTEM.def] Error 1

rm m2/gm2-compiler-boot/P0SyntaxCheck.mod m2/gm2-compiler-boot/PCBuild.mod gccgo.pod gforttran.pod gcc.pod 
m2/gm2-compiler-boot/P1Build.mod m2/gm2-compiler-boot/P2Build.mod m2/gm2-compiler-boot/P3Build.mod 
m2/gm2-compiler-boot/PHBuild.mod

make[2]: Leaving directory '/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc'
Makefile:4619: recipe for target 'all-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/nobackup/builddir/build'
Makefile:1036: recipe for target 'all' failed

It seems unnecessary to need to provide that to GCC in order to build. Am I missing something?
EDIT:
Running the build in single-threaded mode run the following command and yields this error.
Makefile:1157: update target 'gcc-main.o' due to ../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/gcc-main.cc
g++ -fno-PIE -c   -g -O2    -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions 
-fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing-Wwrite-strings 
-Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wconditionally-supported ... -DHAVE_CONFIG_H 
-I. -I. -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/. -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/. 
-I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../include -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../libcpp/include 
-I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../libcody -I/nobackup/builddir/gmp/include 
-I/nobackup/builddir/mpfr/include -I/nobackup/builddir/mpc/include 
-I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd 
-I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/../libbacktrace -I/nobackup/builddir/isl/include 
-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_MONOTONIC=1 -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CLOCK_REALTIME=1 -o gcc-main.o -MT 
gcc-main.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/gcc-main.TPo ../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/gcc-main.cc
mv ./.deps/gcc-main.TPo ./.deps/gcc-main.Po



../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/m2/Make-lang.in:1542: target 'm2/gm2config.aci' does not exist
NEW_SRCDIR=`../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/m2/tools-src/calcpath ../ ../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc m2` ; \
        export NEW_SRCDIR ; \
cd m2 ; \
if echo -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE | grep \\-DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE; then \
    AR= ; \
    export AR ; \
    RANLIB ; \
    exprot RANLIB ; \
    /bin/bash -c '${NEW_SRCDIR}/configure --srcdir=${NEW_SRCDIR} \
        --target=riscv64-unknown-elf --program-suffix= \
        --includedir=`echo /nobackup/builddir/riscv64-unknown-elf/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown
            -elf/13.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/sys-include | sed -e :a -e 
            's,[^/]*/\.\.\/,,' -e ta` --libdir=/nobackup/builddir/riscv64-unknown-elf/lib \
        --libexecdir=/nobackup/builddir/riscv64-unknown-elf/libexec' ; \
    else \
        /bin/bash -c '${NEW_SRCDIR}/configure --srcdir= \
            --target=riscv64-unknown-elf --program-suffix=' ; \
    fi
/nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2
-DIN_GCC -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE
/bin/bash: /nobackup/builddir/build/gcc/m2: Is a directory
../../gcc-13.2.0/gcc/m2/Make-lang.in:1542: recipe for target 'm2/gm2config.aci' failed
make[2]: *** [m2/gm2config.aci] Error 126


The error code looks like it is trying to run that flag string. The "as" there is a wrapper script created by gcc build process to run the assembler, and it is misbehaving because one of the variables is unset. Something went wrong during gcc configure step, like maybe it failed to find a matching cross-compiler assembler?

Run make again after the error in a single-threaded mode. What is the last command it tries to run before this happen (may need to add --trace if it doesn't print by default).

Ran it through a single-threaded build with trace enabled. Looks like a new error came up.

I should note that this is definitely NOT risc-v specific. I tried compiling with a target architecture of 'arm-none-eabi' and had the same error, but with it looking for '-march=armv4t'.
